# What is the best way to handle expires_in data in the model table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-design

I have licenses that are purchased and become user_licenses that users get when they purchase the license. The time a license is valid for, cost, name and description are all stored in the license table.

When the license is purchased the expiration is set on the user_license (Date.now + License.expiration_years)

So basically the user license expiration date is:

```
UserLicense.expiration_date = Date.now + expires_in_days.days + expires_in_weeks.weeks + expires_in_months.months + expires_in_years.years
```

Is there another way to handle the `expire_in_*` columns? Maybe using a sort of jsonb structure?

```
# license table:

      t.string :name, null: false
      t.string :description
      t.integer :amount, default: 0, null: false
      t.jsonb :details, default: {}, null: false
      t.boolean :hidden
      t.string :currency
      t.integer :expires_in_days, default: 0, null: false
      t.integer :expires_in_weeks, default: 0, null: false
      t.integer :expires_in_months, default: 0, null: false
      t.integer :expires_in_years, default: 0, null: false
```

Comment: Is the expiration date now + years, or the now + days + weeks ... calculation?  Just storing the date seems a lot simpler to me.

Comment: @Andrew Yeah that the calculation for the user_license expiration based on the license `expire_in_*` (expires_in_days, expires_in_weeks...). Can't just store a date because it is a date range for the expiration date. And there really isnt a way to store a time range with days, weeks and months in one field, because it is not a date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Postgres [interval type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-datetime.html). This type represents a duration of time such as:

```
INTERVAL '1 year 2 months 3 days'
```

Rails has supported [the interval type natively since 6.1](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-6-1-adds-postgresql-interval-data-type) and maps it to an [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html). You can use it in previous versions but you need to manually parse the string. If you want to advance a date from a duration you can use [Time#advance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/Time.html#method-i-advance):

```
# Three days, four hours and 30 minutes
Time.current.advance(
  ActiveSupport::Duration.parse("P3DT4H30M").parts
)
```

Not only that but you can also use intervals to do database queries with relative time without going insane.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in other comments, unless there is a valid reason not mentioned in the question to store specific days/weeks/months/years for future expiration in the database, you avoid a lot of trouble by just storing the expiration date.

Then from this date you could calculate whatever you want.

Comment: The question is slightly confusing but I think I have it figured out. The actual expiry date of a single license is stored on the `user_license` table while `licenses` stores an interval of how long the licence lasts if you bought it today - eg. you're buying a 6 month or 1 year contact.  Thats why a simple date won't work.